# What kind of app should I write to gain control of a lost Nexus ... that I see in my Google Device Manager?

Tags: android, security, mobile, device-manager

I have (had) a Nexus device and lost it while backpacking in Europe.  One year later, I've been able to see it online at the [Google Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager?u=0), near southern Italy.

Despite me trying (and failing) to contact the owners of the Hostel, I've been unable to get the device erased or returned to me.  For the past several months the device has been powered on and active.

My goal is to write an application, deploy it to the app store, and use my Google Play account (connected to the device) to download the app as I could do in the screen below.

[image]

I want the app to either

- Erases the device
- Locks the screen with a "Reward" message
- An audio message
- Something else?

.. the issue is that the user might not "permit" certain supervision activity if the OS requires it. (Device Administrator for example)

**Question**

What can I do on a 4.x Nexus, not requiring additional interactive permissions, after I send an app from the app store, to accomplish the goal of notifying the user (in Italian) or erasing sensitive material?

Comment: If you're unable to use Device Manager to wipe your device (why is that?), what makes you think remotely installing an App will work?

Comment: @adelphus My only option is to "set up lock an erase", not "erase" as my other devices allow me

Comment: well if you think it has been stolen, you can use jRAT to create a "remote connection" of sorts